Form Constraints on File Skipped
I'm working with Symfony 5.4.
I tried using the constraints parameter in my FileType.php but it looks like it doesnt work, nothing seems happen, do u have an idea ? I checked the documentation and my code seems correct
<?php

class FileType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('file', SymfonyFileType::class, [
                'label' => 'add a file',
                'constraints' => [
                        new File([
                            'mimeTypes' => [
                                "application/pdf",
                            ],
                            'mimeTypesMessage' => 'test'
                        ])
                ]
            ])

And here's my Controller code for the File Entity with the create function.
There's no validation rules here:
<?php

//

/**
 * File controller.
 *
 * @Route("file")
 */
class FileController extends AbstractController
{

    /**
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param TranslatorInterface $translator
     * @param Session $session
     * @param FileManager $fileManager
     *
     * @return RedirectResponse | Response
     *
     * @Route("/new/{entity}/{entity_id}", name="file_new", methods={"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request, TranslatorInterface $translator, Session $session, FileManager $fileManager)
    {
        $file = new File();
        $form = $this->createForm(FileType::class, $file);

        if ($request->get('entity') == 'identite') {
            $form->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['validation_groups' => 'identite', 'label' => 'Upload', 'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-valid']]);
        } else {
            $form->remove('typeDocument');
            $form->add('save', SubmitType::class, ['label' => 'Upload', 'attr' => ['class' => 'btn btn-valid']]);
        }
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        $file->setEntityLabel($request->get('entity'));
        $file->setEntityId($request->get('entity_id'));

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            $em->persist($file);
            $em->flush();

            $fileManager->indexFile($file);

            $session->getFlashBag()->set('success', $translator->trans('ADD_FILE'));

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl($file->getEntityLabel() . '_show', [
                    'id' => $file->getEntityId()]) . '#files');
        }

        return $this->render('file/new.html.twig', [
            'file' => $file,
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ]);
    }


if you don't indicate 'multiple' => true then, you probably can't use All constraint. either remove All constraint or set 'multiple' => true

I removed the All constraint, still when I try to upload a .txt file or a png image for example, the form still submits without sending me error message :(

add your controller code to the op

Is your file element in a collection / embedded form ?

@craigh I edited my question to add the controller

@DylanKAS No its a simple form (called in a modal)

Are you using the correct use statements, also I see you have called your form FileType and used SymfonyFileType, seems confusing.

@Bossman Here's the use statements:
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FileType as SymfonyFileType;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\File;

Okay, you should edit your question with these. I see from above if you submit a .txt file for example, does this get uploaded to your upload directory? And if you try a .pdf does that get uploaded? It could be you're not displaying the error in your template, does the Symfony profiler show any form errors?
